# Designing and implementing hiding top bar in iOS 7

Tags: ios, interface-builder, ios7

The Instagram.app was redesigned for iOS and its UI was spotlighted by Apple in "Designed for iOS7" category on AppStore.

One of the fascinating effects in this app is a top bar that is hiding while moving the tableview with recent posts up.

I've captured a short video demonstrating this effect: http://youtu.be/NeKYoc6I8Wo

How can I implement this neat animation?

Is it possible to implement it with IB?

Comment: I used Reflector (http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/) to mirror my iPhone screen to the Mac, and QuickTime to record the video.

Answer (score 0):

One idea: watch the scroll view's `contentOffset` using `NSKeyValueObserving`. In `observeValueForKeyPath:…`, check to see where the `contentOffset` puts the top of the scrollview relative to the full height of the top (navigation?) bar. Use this to create a percentage, then use that percentage to set the height of the bar, the size of the labels, and the opacity of the text (e.g. "the top of the scroll view is 40% of the way down from the top of the bar's full height, so the bar should be 40% of its full height, the labels should be 40% of their full size, and the text should be 40% of its full opacity"). You'll probably have to tweak this as necessary and handle a few edge cases, but that's where I would start.